# Why is "A" greater than "a" in bash string test comparison

Tags: bash

bash string comparison documentation says that it compares lexicographically.

Capital letters come before lowercase letters lexicographically, I would expect this bash comparison to return false, but it is not returning false. Why?

```
[[ "a" < "A" ]]; echo $?

0
```

As well, if I append a 0 onto the first string, it now returns the opposite result. Why does this change the result? Shouldn't only the first letter matter?

```
[[ "a0" < "A" ]]; echo $?

1
```

Comment: Depends on your locale. Specifically, your locale's collation order.

Comment: How can I tell bash that I want these comparison to work similar to C's strcmp? I just want regular vanilla string compares..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The problem here is not the comparison ; the problem is because OP uses the exit status `$?` to retrieve the test result....

Comment: @ringø, ...can you convince me of the truth of that claim? `$?` is a perfectly legitimate way to determine whether a test has succeeded. Yes, it conflates the success of the test itself with the result of the test, but that's still how the UNIX `test` command, and all its derivatives, does things.

Comment: My problem was resolved by setting using LC_ALL=C

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `[[ "a" < "A" ]] && echo ok` displays **ok**

Comment: @ringø, ...what does that have to do with anything at all? The `$?` is that of the compound command, thus that of `echo` in that case -- though in that scenario the exit status of the test was likewise `0`. However: What the output is **for you** depends on your configured locale. Unless you have the same locale the OP had, you can't reproduce their behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But... doing `[[ "a" < "A" ]] && echo 1` displays **1**, while `[[ "a" < "A" ]]; echo $?` displays **0**, isn't that strange to you?

Comment: @ringø: In UNIX exit status, 0 is success (truthy) and any nonzero value is a failure (falsey). Since the OP says their comparison is "not returning false", they clearly already know this.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy wow, really need to sleep now! sorry for the botherness...